# How to use grep to match a string containing [], the characters in [] are composed of uppercase and lowercase letters and +#?

Tags: regex, grep

The string is like this:

```
I am a [PHP] engineer, not a [Java] engineer, nor a [C++] engineer, nor a [C#] engineer.
```

I wrote this expression but it didn't work.

```
grep -n '\[([a-zA-Z+#]+)\]' filename
```

Comment: You probably want `grep -oP '\[\K[A-Za-z#+]+(?=])' filename`

Comment: In regexps you should use `[:alpha:]` instead of `a-zA-Z` for portability across locales unless you have a specific reason to want to exclude alphabetic characters outside of that set.

Answer (score 2):

grep recognizes only [BREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) unless one of `-P`, `-E`, and `-r` flags is specified. And also, parens are unneeded there.

You should either use BRE equivalent of `+`

```
grep -n '\[[a-zA-Z+#]\{1,\}\]' filename
```

or specify `-E` flag to make it recognize [EREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (which is indeed less portable than the former but easier to read)

```
grep -E -n '\[[a-zA-Z+#]+\]' filename
```

Comment: `\+` is probably preferable over `\{1,\}` but if you aren't capturing the match (with `-o` or similar) you don't really care whether there's more than one match anyway.

Comment: @tripleee `\+` is not a part of POSIX BREs, it is a GNU extension as far as I know

Comment: @tripleee so you're saying `*` is enough? Wouldn't it match `[]` too?

Comment: No, I mean "one" is good enough if you look for "one or more" but don't actually care exactly.

Comment: @tripleee Nah, I can't understand. Show me an example if possible, or post another answer and I'll delete mine

Comment: `grep 'ab'` prints exactly the same lines as `grep 'ab+'`. You don't care whether there are in fact two `b`s or three or more for this particular use case.

Comment: But I missed the trailing `\]` which means you do need the repetition. Sorry for wasting your time here.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to just use this to find strings within `[...]`?

```
$ grep -Eo '\[[^]]+\]' file
[PHP]
[Java]
[C++]
[C#]
```

Instead of having to list what chars can be inside the square brackets the above just looks for anything except the closing bracket, `]`.